# Submitting modified model back to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an edit page and I want to submit some changes to the server when I press a button and then change the div of a given part of the page called #main to another page so as to update it with the new information.

To do this I don't think I can use a submit button (correct me if I am wrong?) so I am using a jquery function to handle the click and changing of the selected part of the page.

Currently the object sent to the server is empty and not the modified contents.

Here is the view that has the issue:

```
@model Project.Models.ExampleModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit Example: @Model.name</legend>
        <br/>
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.name)
        <br/>
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.dropdown)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.dropdown, Model.dropdowns)
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="button" data-edit-id="@Model.id" value="Submit Changes" />
    </fieldset>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[data-edit-id]').on('click', function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('data-edit-id');
            console.log(id);
            $.post('Home/EditPage', '@Model');
            $("#main").load("/Home/NewDivPage?id=" + id);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: If you are manually performing a posting action using the jquery handler **post** (that is an ajax call) you will need to read all HTML inputs, create a JSON object (or other format) and send it to the server. You cannot use **@Model** on that context.

Comment: I see, that was what I was trying to avoid doing but I guess I will have to do it! Thanks

Comment: Take a look into the ajax mvc helper, like the **@Ajax.BeginForm()**...it will help you to avoid some undesireable client side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong

```
$.post('Home/EditPage', '@Model');
```

`@Model` is evaluated at server side, and you get simple string on client side with that expression. You should dynamically serialize `form` and send its contents to server

```
$.post('Home/EditPage', $('form').serialize());
```

Also, the last statement should be passed as callback to $.post, so it will be executed after post has finished loading

```
$.post('Home/EditPage', $('form').serialize(), function(){
   $("#main").load("/Home/NewDivPage?id=" + id); 
});
```

Comment: How would I handle this server side? The same way I would if the model was sent back using a submit button?